# Serializing a tree structure using JAXB in Java

Tags: java, xml, serialization, tree, jaxb

So I have a tree implemented my custom tree structure moreless like this:

The tree class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Tree {

   Set<? extends TreeNode> nodes;
   @XmlElement
   Set<? extends TreeNode> getNodes() {...}
}
```

The abstract node:

```
public abstract class Node {
   Set<? extends Node> children;
   private String name;

   @XmlAttribute
   public String getName() {...}
   @XmlElement
   public abstract Set<? extends Node> getChildren();

}
```

The group (could contain groups and entities):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "group")
public class Group extends Node {

    private final Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>();
    private final Set<Entity> entities = new HashSet<Entity>();
    public Set<Group> getGeoups() { ... }
    public Set<Entity> getEntities() { ... }
}
```

The node:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "entity")
public class Entity extends Node {

    public Set<DashboardNode> getChildren() {
        return Collections.<DashboardNode> emptySet();
    }
}
```

My problem is, that JAXB doesn't use diffrent names for groups and entities. I would like to get result similar to:

```
<tree>
   <node>
       <group>
            <group>
                <entity/>
            </group>
       </group>
   </node>
   <node>
       <group>
           <entity/>
       </group>
       <group>
       </group>
       <entity/>
   </node>
</tree>
```

And I get this instead:

```
<tree>
   <node>
       <children>
            <children>
                <children/>
            </children>
       </children>
   </node>
   (...)
</tree>
```

IF i remove the annotation in my abstract node class on the getChildren() method I would reveive only this:

```
<tree>
   <node>
   </node>
  <node>
   </node>
</tree>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `@XmlElements` annotation, adding a suitable one of these to the children property of `Node` should achieve what you're after.

Comment: What I did is added annotation to `Set<? extends TreeNode> getNodes()` in my Node class:

        `@XmlElements(  
        {@XmlElement(name = "group", type = Group.class),
         @XmlElement(name = "entity", type =Entity.class)})`

This was almost perfect except for the fact, that all "entities in griups were doubled. To prevent this I had to add `@XmlTransient` annotation to `getEntities()` in my Group class (cause, as I suppose, entities are already handled by `getChildren()` method in my abstract Node class.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @dstronczak in fact, thinking about it further a better approach would be to use `@XmlElementRef`.  "Example 1" on [its JavaDoc page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html) is pretty much exactly your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your group 'is-a' node. What is the serialiser to do when it encounters an object that both has 'children' and has 'groups'?

It may be better to avoid the java inheritance altogether.

Actually, you don't have a `@XMLElement` annotation on `getGeoups()` [sic] or `getEntities()` either...